# Excel VBA compare cells against column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare the D column cells against each other. If the cells (d2,d3) have the same data then it would go onto the next cell (D4) and compare cells D3 and D4. If it is false then it should add a row between them and put the data in the lower cell in the new row.

IE

```
ljsdahgfoshfv
ljsdahgfoshfv
ljsdahgfoshfv
lldkjafsf;ksn
dslkfndjlnvfs
dslkfndjlnvfs
dslkfndjlnvfs
```

would translate into

```
ljsdahgfoshfv
ljsdahgfoshfv
ljsdahgfoshfv
lldkjafsf;ksn
lldkjafsf;ksn
dslkfndjlnvfs
dslkfndjlnvfs
dslkfndjlnvfs
dslkfndjlnvfs
dslkfndjlnvfs
```

Example table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub insertRows()

    ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Select

    Do Until Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        Set curCell = ActiveCell
        Set nextCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)

        If nextCell.Value <> curCell.Value Then

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select

        Else

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&t=3124s) on YouTube.

Answer (score -1):

This code seems to do what you describe, but according to my understanding you should have one less row of that last item in your result.  In any event, by stepping through the code you should be able to modify as needed to get the result you need. If not, please ask questions. The `.select` statements are only put in so that you can follow the logic as you step through the code, and should be deleted once you understand how the code works.

```
Option Explicit
Sub compareD()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("D1")
While r <> ""
  If r = r.Offset(1, 0) Then
    r.Select
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
   Else
    Rows(r.Row + 1).Insert
    r.Select
    r.Offset(1, 0) = r.Offset(2, 0)
    Set r = r.Offset(2, 0)
  End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: is there a way to add the data to column b as well?

Comment: Yes definitely. I'm not sure if you mean making a duplicate of the same data? If so then r.offset(0,-2) gets you to column B from column D. I encourage you to go ahead and add code 1 line at time and then step through it as a way to learn

Comment: Thanks I figured it out whenever i deconstructed it    
Option Explicit
Sub compareD()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("D1")
While r <> ""
  If r = r.Offset(1, 0) Then
    r.Select
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
   Else
    Rows(r.Row + 1).Insert
    r.Select
    r.Offset(1, -2) = r.Offset(2, 0)
    Set r = r.Offset(2, 0)
  End If
Wend
End Sub